# Are there any cafes serving breakfast in Bakewell / Peak District that are open around 8 AM on Sundays?

Tags: uk, food-and-drink, camping, peak-district

I will be camping near [Bakewell](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=bakewell&hnear=Bakewell,%20Derbyshire,%20United%20Kingdom&gl=uk&t=m&z=14) this Saturday and I wanted to eat some warm breakfast in a nice cafe on Sunday. Does anyone know which cafe would be open around 8:00 AM and serve breakfast?

Comment: If you find a pub that does B&B they will often sell you a breakfast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably struggle. Rural areas such as this in the UK aren't known for long opening hours or 24h-style service. 8am on a Sunday may be difficult, although by 9am you might have more options. Your best bet would be to call a few places - I wouldn't trust any online information you find on a third-party site, and cafes are quite likely not to have a website of their own. I just searched on Yelp for [breakfast places near Bakewell](http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=breakfast&find_loc=Bakewell,%20Derbyshire,%20UK&ns=1&ls=219c578eb102fe27#!) and it turned up a few. That might be a start.

Comment: I've noticed in some parts of the world I've visited lately that a lot of bars and cafes that don't have websites have Facebook pages - so it might be worth looking there.

Comment: After checking in person, I can confirm that all the cafe's seem to open at 9:00 AM. There is quite a few of them, so everyone should find something suitable.

Answer (score 8):

The Bakewell Tart, Matlock St, Bakewell, DE45 1EE.
FAB breakfasts, cosy and friendly. Open 8.30 Sundays.

Answer (score 0):

Wyes Waters Tea Rooms open 8.30am on Sunday mornings. One of the first!

Comment: Address?  Link? Or at least the town.